# Quick start for WebRTC and MAMP

Tags: javascript, html5-video, mamp, webrtc

I am just getting started with WebRTC. I've done the demos here:

https://apprtc.appspot.com/?r=07503231
and
https://github.com/gandg/webrtc-ios

Now I would like to run it on my own network. I've setup rfc5766-turn-server which seems to running just fine.

What next? If possible I don't want to use Node.js. I have MAMP or Apache so would like a simple example of video chat using plain HTML/JS or PHP.

Anyone have a simple example that is not some 3rd party trying to license a product to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look below site, it may helps to you.

http://blog.printf.net/articles/2013/05/17/webrtc-without-a-signaling-server/

Comment: Ok, after another look this is looking very promising.